# Почему стоит двоеточие, а не тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, двоеточие, пояснительные

> Тема урока: сложные предложения.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому правилу стоит двоеточие? Заранее премного благодарен!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Постановка знака препинания будет зависеть от контекста, от ситуации, в которой используется слово "тема". Возможны варианты:

***Тема урока — "Сложные предложения".***
***Тема урока: "Сложные предложения".***

> Ср. различные, хотя внешне схожие случаи:
> *На приёмных экзаменах по русскому языку и литературе абитуриентам были предложены темы: «Сравнительная характеристика Онегина и Печорина», «Основные образы романа В. Пастернака “Доктор Живаго”», «Место В. В. Маяковского в русской литературе»* (**после обобщающего слова *темы* ставится двоеточие**);
> *Абитуриенты писали сочинение на тему «М. Горький — писатель-реалист»* (**после определяемого существительного *на тему* не ставится никакого знака препинания**);
> *Тема доклада — «Современные молодые художники»* (**тире между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки**);
> *Тема урока: «Бессоюзное сложное предложение»* (**запись на доске в виде заголовка, в котором вторая часть поясняет первую; между ними ставится двоеточие**).

Источник — [справочник Розенталя](https://old-rozental.online/punctum_uk.php?pid=77).

Например, в таком тексте логично поставить **тире**:

*Завтра у Марии Петровны будет открытый урок. Тема [урока] — "Сложные предложения".*

**Двоеточие** обычно ставят в "шапке" плана урока, реферата или любой другой работы:

*Тема: "Сложные предложения"* (часто без кавычек).
*Цель:...

Задачи:...

Оборудование:...*